# move focus to another asp.net control after ajax toolkit calendar extender selection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender

I am having trouble finding an answer to this problem.

What I am trying to do is this;

I have an asp.net (aspx) page that has two text boxes on it (among other controls) that have an Ajax Toolkit Calendar Extender on them. The first text box get focus and the calendar control appears and I am able to select a date just fine.

Here is my problem. After the date is selected for the first text box with the calendar control I want the second text box to automatically have the same date entered into it and the focus moved to a button (btnSearch) not the second text box.

I am using VB in code behind. I must not be wording my searches correctly because I can't seem to find anything close to solving this.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how this can be done? I am open to using JQuery if I have to but would prefer not to.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Note: There is no code to show because I can't find anything to try.

Update:
Here is the html I have:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbDateStart" CssClass="form-control input-lg" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false" OnTextChanged="txbDateStart_TextChanged"/>
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" PopupButtonID="imgPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="txbDateStart" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" PopupPosition="Right" />

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txbDateEnd" CssClass="form-control input-lg" Visible="false" ToolTip="Click to change End Date" ReadOnly="true" />
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txbDateEnd" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" />
```

Comment: You should still show the relevant code/markup related to your question. You mentioned a page with two textboxes and an AJAX Toolkit Calendar Extender. That would give an answerer a starting point.

Comment: Nobody has any suggestions on this??